# Fast and small offline Android PDF-Viewer

Tags: android, pdf, android-library, pdf-viewer

Although this kind of question is asked very often, I`m also looking for an Android PDF Viewer.
My Problem is, that my App comes with some conditions which must be solved.
The PDF-Viewer should be:

---

- small (there is only a Viewer needed so every MB for special functions is too much ;-))
- fast (very fast)
- work inside a Fragment
- working with Android 4.1

---

I already tried mupdf, so you don't need to mention it. Actually I`m working with 
[android-pdfview][1], which works perfect but isn`t fast enough.

So if you have worked with an Viewer which matches my conditions, I would be very pleased to hear from you :-)

Ps. A commercial product is also no problem.

Comment: [1] above should be https://github.com/JoanZapata/android-pdfview

Comment: Hi, thank you very much that looks great :-)

Answer (score 0):

Android PDFView is a library which provides a fast PDFView component for Android

https://github.com/JoanZapata/android-pdfview

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. This lib is the one I`m actually working with. I tried to mention it in the text but I crashed the link. Unfortunately it is too slow for my Use-Case.

Comment: this library is deprecatedted